# not able to get data in javascript from c# in asp.net

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, webforms

alert message not printing value from myfunction() method
on page.aspx

```
 <div class="form-group row">
                    <label for="colFormLabelLg" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label col-form-label-lg">User Name</label>
                    <div class="col-sm-10">
                      <asp:TextBox class="form-control form-control-lg" ID="username" onfocusout="myFunction()" placeholder="UserName" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    </div>
                </div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function myFunction() {
        var ques = <%= myFunction() %>;
        alert(ques + "is your question ");
    }
</script>
```

on page.aspx.cs ( In this i have created sql connection Globally)

```
protected string myFunction()
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.CommandText = "select Pass from Counselor where UserName = @username";
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@username", username.Text);
            conn.Open();
            try
            {
                SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
                if (rdr.Read())
                {
                    String question = rdr[1].ToString();
                    return question;
                }
                else
                {
                    dangerMessage.Visible = true;
                    dangermsg.InnerText = "User Not found";
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                dangerMessage.Visible = true;
                dangermsg.InnerText = "error from finding user \n" + ex;
            }
            conn.Close();
            return null;
        }
```

in javascript alert message is not able to read data 
don't Know why but I think myFunction() in javascript is not calling Properly

Comment: try onclientclick="myFunction()" if button, if textbox onKeyPress="javascript:"myFunction()"

Comment: @justinmontalban no it's not working. my function is calling but when I put <%=muFunction%> in alert method it shows "page say Undefine".

Comment: @justinmontalban i try, not working

Comment: The function is being executed on the server and the return value is included in the page.  All this happens before the page is sent to the browser, so at the time that the function is executed, `@username` is not defined and your query will return nothing.

Comment: try this instead of = sign use # <%#myFunction()%> ;

Comment: @justinmontalban It's Javascript - it will not run the C# function when the Javascript function is executed, since it's already been run on the server *before the page was served to the client*.

Comment: @Archer But when I do same in my friends pc it works, data was coming from c#

Comment: You have 2 options here - 1, go with old school postback so they submit the form with their username and you then run your query and return the result, or 2, you start looking at AJAX.  I'd strongly recommend you do some reading about the ASP.Net page life cycle, because your current method is simply not possible.

Comment: No, it was not, unless the `@username` var was populated at the time the page loaded, not afterwards.

Comment: @Archer yes this is happening, when I debug my code I found that function is calling at page load  time

Comment: This will help you understand where you've gone wrong... [ASP.Net Page Life Cycle](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/8911c4/page-life-cycle-with-examples-in-Asp-Net/)

Comment: @justinmontalban no # is not working

Comment: did you add ScriptManager to your page?..
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server" EnablePageMethods="true"/>

Comment: @Uzay They want to react to client-side events by running server-side code with client-side variables.  That won't help at all.

Answer (score -2):

<strike>Try to put quotes around your function call:</strike>

```
var ques = '<%= myFunction() %>';
```

Edit: I see now that you are expecting the C# method `myFunction` to be called when leaving the textbox. This is not how it works, the method will be called on page load and you will have to move to some sort of AJAX solution. Archer made some pretty comments about it above.